# How to use Client Application Services with WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

I followed these two tutorial to get Client Application services working using WCF instead of the traditional web services project:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398990.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546195.aspx

But when configuring the winforms project services tab with the wcf services location, the generated code in app.config points to a "Authentication_JSON_AppService.axd" service uri that doesn't exist.

How can I use Client Application Services using WCF as the "transport" and still use the services tab to configure the settings on the client windows application?

Thanks